# What is the meaning of "Complete and Send Review" in Elsevier journal under History tab

Tags: peer-review, elsevier, journal-workflow

What is the meaning of the "Complete and Send Review" status in the History tab of an Elsevier journal?

[image: History Tab]

Comment: What is the background of this situation? Are you a reviewer or a submitter? What happened to the paper before this?

Comment: Before it was "under review " I'm a submitter..... Do you have any idea about this status

Comment: Are you sure to be submitter for this paper? The role is reviewer...strange status...maybe another paper where u are a reviewer? Check the id

Comment: Yes I am sure.. I'm the submitter of this paper.. This is my id only..  Might be they would have change the system... I'm in confusion right now

Comment: Sounds like something got seriously wrong here. If you haven’t done so, I suggest that you contact Elsevier. (Should they fail to react to this, you can try to review your own paper and rub it in their face.)

Comment: Ya, it only 16 days since my submission.  Let me wait for some more days/weeks and see. Thanks a lot.. Happy new year.

Comment: @imran: Contact them immediately. This does not seem to be a frequent bug (at least nobody reported having the same problem here). Thus, there is no reason to expect anyone at Elsevier to be aware of the problem. The editor will very likely notice this at best in a few weeks or months when the reviews are due. It could very well be that your paper is not assigned reviewers when it should be or similar and waiting with reporting this problem delays the review process with no benefit.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft it has been only 19 days since my submission. I think it would be better to wait for some more days. Because it shows the current status as "Under Review" which is displayed under the title of our paper.

But when we click on the title of our paper and go inside a page. In that page under the "history" tab I could able to see the  status as "Complete and Send Review".
 
This  place i am confusing a lot about to consider which status (Either "Under Review" or "Complete and Send Review").

Thanks for your guidance. see the new screen shot I mentioned above

Comment: the site has been updated, and they hid the history tab !!!!

Answer (score 1):

From your expanded screenshot, I would guess that *complete and send review* is supposed to actually mean *review complete**d** and sen**t**,* i.e., one of the reviewers completed their review and submitted it to the editorial system.

However, educated guessing is all I can do, and only asking Elsevier can provide clarification. It may be a more serious bug. Either way, there is something to improve here, so it cannot harm filing a bug report.

Comment: +1 There is a forum in China for econ. Somebody's got the very same status after sending a paper to Elsevier journal and raised a question about it. The answer is about the same as you said "one of the reviewers completed their review and submitted it to the editorial system" if translated into English. See the link in Chinese http://bbs.pinggu.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&action=printable&tid=3790480

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yes you are right. I messaged the Elsevier support team and asked about the meaning fot that status.. They said the same as what you mentioned. They said one of the reviewer has completed and submitted the manuscript to the editor and the editor is waiting for review from some other reviewer. 
but I am not sure about how many reviewer will be reviewing my paper.
Finally confusion cleared.. Big Thanks to all

Comment: @imran: Did you poke them to change the wording of that status?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft no, they saying that it is the correct status

Comment: My journal status is in same stage.. "under Review" for 54 days. Do I need to mail to the editor or simply wait for some more days.. Any Idea plz

Comment: @imran: That depends strongly on your field and even the journal. In my field it’s very long; in mathematics it’s the norm. You best consult with somebody from your very subfield on this.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft  it is in telematics and informatics journal in elsevier.. As I mentioned in the picture. it is still same...

Comment: @imran: I cannot deduce that from your picture, but anyway: Only somebody familiar with that very subfield will be able to give you an answer on the review times of that journal. You might also look at the journal’s page whether they have some statistics on their average review times.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft it shows 9.2 weeks for first decisions

Comment: @Wrzlprmft ooo before it shows 7.2 weeks as on 2014 They have updated this... So let me wait for another 2 weeks.. Do they follow that schedule... ?

Comment: @imran: It’s an average, not a schedule. Review times are usually subject to great variation. By the way: Take a look at [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/7734), if you haven’t already done so.