# What does this Elsevier revision report mean?

Tags: publications, peer-review, elsevier

This is a review report of an article on the EVISE revision status website:
[image]

Does this mean my article was rejected? Why there isn't any "Complete and send review" for the second reviewer? And why is the status of the article "Decision Pending"?

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of “Complete and Send Review” in Elsevier journal under History tab](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/60898/7734). If I would have to wager a guees, it seems that Elsevier has shipped a confusing new status interface …

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thank you for your comment. Do you think this a problem in interface or a problem of editor in chief!?

Comment: The interface. File a bug report. If they get sufficiently many, they might do something about it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft. The support team of Elsevier answer : This is problem of the journal!. If this is problem of journal, the decision made by only respond of one reviewer not two. Is this true?

Comment: Well, you would have to ask the journal. However, *decision pending* and *reject* almost directly contradict each other. It could be that the latter actually means *recommend rejection* and the decision is pending because some other editor has to confirm or decline the associate editor’s decision. In this case, however, Elsevier is to blame for the confusing interface once more.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers and comments. This was some bug in EVISE system. Supporting section of EVISE is trying to fix it in next updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for all of your answers and comments. This was some bug in EVISE system. Supporting section of EVISE is trying to fix it in next updates.

Answer (score 13):

My reading is that the associate editor has rejected the article and it just has to be formalized by either the editorial staff or the editor-in-chief.

Prepare for an email with bad news :-(

Comment: Now, with the miracle of the Internet, you can find out about your rejected paper even before you get the email!

Comment: Is it possible to say that an editor-in-chief communicates a revision by mail? or the editor-in-chief sends an email, does it mean that it is always a rejection?

Comment: @optimalcontrol -- are you asking whether any email is always bad news? No, EiCs also communicate acceptances by email.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not necessarily a reject. I saw the same status on one of my papers for 2 days and finally it was a minor revision. 
My paper status changed from "under review" to  "Ready for decision" to "Decision pending" and finally "Revision requested". 
I think if an associate editor rejects, EIC will never go for a minor revision. 
Additionally, after reviewing the comments of reviewers i realized that it should be a minor revision (Rev1: Accept, Rev2: Some minor things relate to text and format, rev3: Few suggestions).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the Associate Editor of a journal makes a recommendation about whether the paper should be accepted or rejected. In your case, the AE has recommended a rejection. However, the final decision is taken by the EIC. That is why the status is still showing "Decision pending." Once the EIC formally takes the decision and communicates it you to over email, the decision making process will be considered formally closed.

In most cases, the EIC’s decision matches with the AE’s recommendation, and the EIC's decision is a mere formality. However, in some exceptional cases, the EIC might review the manuscript himself and give a different decision. However, such cases are extremely rare, and you should be mentally prepared for a rejection.